# PCD viewer problem for Object Detection using Kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, 3d-object-recognition, ros-pcl, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on object detection using ROS-PCL. Using a Kinect camera I save point clouds generated by the following code in a .pcd file. My problem is that I am unable to see the object as a point cloud in the PCD file viewer. Is the code a problem? It generates a PCD file but I do not know if it works on giving a proper point cloud in .pcd. I just obtain a straight line of points in the middle of the PCD viewer for all objects. Please help.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> PC;    

void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& msg)
{
     printf("Writing the file...\n");
     pcl::fromROSMsg(*msg, PC);
     int a = pcl::io::savePCDFileBinary"/home/rootx/pcl_proj/pcd/temp.pcd", PC);
     printf("Saved the pcd file...%d Return %d\n", PC.points.size(), a);

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     ros::init(argc, argv, "sub_pcl");
     ros::NodeHandle nh;
     ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscrib<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("points2", 1, callback);
     ros::spin();
}
```

I tried this command to view pcd file pcd_viewer:
rosrun perception_pcl pcd_viewer "filename"

Edit:
Using pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGBA PC; instead of the statement used in the code, as suggested, gives an error:
[ERROR] [1330465520.406938763]: Failed to find a field named: 'rgba'. Cannot convert message to PCL type.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pcl::InvalidConversionException'
what(): Failed to find a field named: 'rgba'. Cannot convert message to PCL type.
Aborted.

Does it need a header file I haven't added perhaps?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28307/pcd-viewer-problem-for-object-detection-using-kinect/) by [PriyankaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1050/priyankap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-02-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should probably have

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA> PC;
```

instead of what you have there.

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2012-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0